# GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE - Limiting Objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE TO ROLE** - This provides read access on 'all' objects in the database to a role, instead how to limit read access to subset of objects on database instead of all objects in database.

Comment: The imported privileges option works only on a shared database, It imports privileges on the entire database. If you need to grant permissions to a subset of objects, you'll need to execute standard grant statements.

Comment: This is a special privilege, like Greg mentioned, specific to shares.  Any roles can still have the normal permissions like SELECT for read access. Note that for shares, you can't grant permissions on individual objects (this is an active feature request).  If you want to only share one table from a shared database to a role, for example, you will need a separate share for this role with just that table.

Comment: @GregPavlik - Thank you. Could you please expand on _**you'll need to execute standard grant statements**_ My understanding is that it is not possible to execute standard grant statements on a share (and imported privileges is the only option)

Comment: @SuzyLockwood - Thanks for the response, while I agree on creating separate share only with that specific table, but my question is more of, if my account is leveraging someone else's share, how do I grant read access to subset of these objects to the users in my account. e.g. SNOWFLAKE share database. Is it possible to create share from a share, which I don't believe so. Any other work around to address my need?

Comment: @JeyJee - You'll need to specify the grants on the account with the outbound share. The account admin on the reader account can create new roles, but the only options for privileges on an inbound share is grant or revoke imported privileges set by the outbound share.

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik

Comment: @Jeyjee how did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating VIEWs with appropriate access privileges on the SHARE objects.

Answer (score -1):

Database Roles (in Public Preview at the time of writing) will enable giving access to subsets of objects in a database: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations#managing-database-object-access-using-database-roles

These Database Roles have a scope limited to objects in the Database they belong to. Database Roles need to be granted to traditional (i.e. account level) roles to give access to specific audiences (i.e. users).